# Find minimum of a column from two date difference in next few of hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Possible ways to find the minimum value of Temperature from next 72 hours to the date "2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z"?

```
SELECT [WeatherForcastDetails].[StartTime],
[WeatherForcastDetails].[Temperature],
[WeatherForcastDetails].[Id] 
FROM [WeatherForcastDetails]WHERE ([WeatherForcastDetails].[StartTime] > N'2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z' 
AND [WeatherForcastDetails].[StartTime] < N'2020-07-10T00:00:00.000Z')
AND [WeatherForcastDetails].[WeatherForcastId] in (6146)
```

[image]

In addition If I have more WeatherForcastIds like

```
SELECT wfd.StartTime,wfd.Temperature,wfd.WeatherForcastId
FROM WeatherForcastDetails as wfd 
WHERE (wfd.StartTime> N'2020-0706T00:00:00.000Z' 
AND wfd.StartTime < N'2020-07-10T00:00:00.000Z')
AND wfd.WeatherForcastId in (6146,6163,6180)
```

[image]

I need to find each day data with lowest temperature for next 72 hours from the given date range in query (checking three days temperature which is min). according to WeatherForcastId, WeatherForcastId can be repeated.

Suggetion

```
select case when val1 < val2 then
           case when val1 < val3 then val1
           else val3
           end
    when val2 < val3 then val2
           else val3
end
```

from cols;

or something like

```
SELECT 
MIN([WeatherForcastDetails].[Temperature]),
MIN([WeatherForcastDetails].[WeatherForcastId]),
(
SELECT MIN(wfd.Temperature)
FROM WeatherForcastDetails as wfd WHERE (wfd.StartTime> N'2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z' 
AND wfd.StartTime < DATEADD(hour, 72,  N'2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z'))) as minTpr
FROM [WeatherForcastDetails]
WHERE ([WeatherForcastDetails].[StartTime] > N'2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z'
AND [WeatherForcastDetails].[StartTime] < N'2020-07-10T00:00:00.000Z')
AND [WeatherForcastDetails].[WeatherForcastId] in
(6146,6163,6180,6198,6238,6244,6250)
GROUP BY [WeatherForcastDetails].[StartTime]
```

Comment: Is it like 72 hours from the current time?

Comment: not from CURRENT time or GETDATE(), Expected result is "64"

Comment: What do you mean by expected result is "64"?

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, N'2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z', N'2020-07-08T13:00:00.000Z') AS DateDiff; result for this is 61 Hours which is less than 72 , So from next 72 hours from the StartDate the resulting Temperature = 64.

Comment: expecting like compare the temperature from the Min(StartDate) to next 72 hours and find the lowest value for temperature .

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
SELECT TOP (1) wfd.*
FROM WeatherForcastDetails wfd
WHERE wfd.StartTime >= '2020-07-06' AND
      wfd.StartTime < DATEADD(hour, 72, '2020-07-06')
      wfd.WeatherForcastId in (6146)
ORDER BY wfd.Temperature ASC;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make queries easier to write and read.
- Square braces make queries harder to write and read and are not necessary usually.
- Date constants do not need the explicit time component.  You can include it, but it does not seem necessary.
- I advise you to avoid `DATEDIFF()`, because it does not do what expect.  It counts "boundaries" between two date/time values, not the actual difference.

EDIT:

If you want to do that for each weather forecast id, then use window functions:

```
SELECT wfd.*
FROM (SELECT wfd.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wfd.WeatherForcastId ORDER BY wfd.Temperature ASC) as seqnum
      FROM WeatherForcastDetails wfd
      WHERE wfd.StartTime >= '2020-07-06' AND
            wfd.StartTime < DATEADD(hour, 72, '2020-07-06')
            wfd.WeatherForcastId in (6146)
     ) wfd
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is not solving my query actually. I had expanded my question pls have a look.

Comment: @ABDULJAMAL . . . Your "edit" entirely changed the question and should have been asked as a NEW question.  The question you actually asked was answered multiple times.  In this case (thinking you were a newer user than you actually are), I edited the answer for your revised question.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, one option is filtering, the sorting the results and retaining the first row only:

```
select top(1) w.*
from WeatherForcastDetails w
where 
    WeatherForcastId = 6146
    and StartTime >= '20200706'
    and StartTime <  '20200710'
order by Temperature
```

Comment: Sorry I'm looking for a general solution.
expecting like compare the temperature from the Min(StartDate) to next 72 hours and find the lowest value for temperature

Comment: If I go for the 37 hours difference SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, N'2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z', N'2020-07-07 13:00:00.000') AS DateDiff; then the lowest Temperature will be 65